# Installation of Extension is extremely slow on remote host w/o internet connection

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

**when the remote box does not have network connection**, I set the setting **remote.downloadExtensionsLocally** to **true** so that VS Code downloads the VSIXs on the client side and install them on the remote box. However, the process of installing the plugin is extremely slow. **The installation of the python plugin takes about 10 minutes, and the installation of the jupyter plugin also takes 4 minutes**. I tried to install these two plugins on another remote host with internet connection for about 9s and 4s respectively.

[#3149](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3149) Through this answer, I know that remote.downloadExtensionsLocally needs to be configured as true when there is no network connection remotely.

As shown in the figure, installation of extension is extremely slow on remote host w/o internet connection. Check the log (*Ctrl+Shift+p -> show logs -> Remote Server*) and find that each plugin takes about 2 minutes from this step (***"[remoteagent] [info] Installing the extension without checking dependencies and pack ms-python.vscode-pylance."***) to the next step. See that the previous information plugin has been downloaded and uploaded locally, **so what operation does not print out in the log take about 2 minutes? Is there any way to shorten the change time?**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5191.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR8bW.png)